# Thevenin impedance and Vab

Tags: voltage, impedance, thevenin

Can I please have the solution to this problem?

I promise this isn't a question in an assignment that I just want to copy lol. I had this in my quiz and I want to see if the solution is the same as mine.

Z<sub>TH</sub> is looking into the circuit from the voltage source therefore the load here is the voltage source so we remove it. 
What about Vab?

[image: picture]

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably just use nodal analysis, with \$V_a\$ (+) on the left side and \$V_b\$ (-) on the right side, \$V_s\$ as your source voltage, and where I'd choose to make the bottom node ground or \$0\:\textrm{V}\$:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_a}{40\:\Omega}+\frac{V_a}{-2 \textrm{j}}&= \frac{V_s}{40\:\Omega}+\frac{0\:\textrm{V}}{-2 \textrm{j}} \\ \therefore V_a &= \frac{\frac{V_s}{40\:\Omega}}{\frac{1}{40\:\Omega}+\frac{1}{-2 \textrm{j}}} = \frac{V_s}{1+\frac{40\:\Omega}{-2 \textrm{j}}}=\frac{60\cdot\left(1-20\textrm{j}\right)}{401} \\ \\ \frac{V_b}{5 \textrm{j}}+\frac{V_b}{20\:\Omega}&= \frac{V_s}{5 \textrm{j}}+\frac{0\:\textrm{V}}{20\:\Omega} \\ \therefore V_b &= \frac{\frac{V_s}{5 \textrm{j}}}{\frac{1}{5 \textrm{j}}+\frac{1}{20\:\Omega}}=\frac{V_s}{1+\frac{5 \textrm{j}}{20\:\Omega}}=\frac{240\cdot\left(4-\textrm{j}\right)}{17}
\end{align*}$$

Then, as you say, just subtract. Since the positive side is on the left, the value is:

$$\begin{align*}V_{ab}&=V_a-V_b=\frac{60\cdot\left(1-20\textrm{j}\right)}{401}-\frac{240\cdot\left(4-\textrm{j}\right)}{17}=\frac{4740}{6817}\cdot\left(-81+16\textrm{j}\right)\\ &\approx -56.321 + 11.12513\textrm{j},~~~~~ 57.41~\angle~168.8^\circ \end{align*}$$

Comment: What about Zth? What I did was I removed the voltage source, assumed that the Vab wire was not there so I just simply added 20 and j5 in series, and 40 and -j2 in series and then added them both in parallel. Is that correct?

Comment: If \$Z_{TH}\$ is just looking at the circuit from the perspective of the voltage source, then it is just the two series branches in parallel. So yes, that's correct. I think I get not quite but about \$13.6 + 2j\$ or \$13.744 \angle 8.3^\circ\$ for that impedance value.

Comment: @user128202 Well, let me know if that's an answer. Is there something else to write out here?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would approach it:

1. \$V_a = V_s \frac {Z_c} {Z_c+Z_r} = 60 (\frac {-j2} {40-j2})\$
2. \$V_b = V_s \frac {Z_r} {Z_l+Z_r} = 60 (\frac {20} {20+j5})\$
3. \$V_{ab} = V_a - V_b = 60 (\frac {-j2} {40-j2} - \frac {20} {20+j5})\$
4. Gnarly algebra.

How does that compare with your approach?